# How to animate 'Raphael' canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, raphael

I'm using the Raphael library to create SVG objects.

To initialise the SVG shape and create a canvas for everything inside, I've used the following line as stated in the documentation:

```
var paper = Raphael(10, 50, 320, 200);
```

I now want to animate the paper and everything inside it, just like I would animate a shape which had been appended to the paper in the following maner:

```
var firstShape = paper.rect(x, y, width, height);
firstShape.animate({x: 100}, 500, "<");
```

When I try something similar with the paper such as:

```
paper.animate({x: 100}, 500, "<");
```

I get the error '`paper.animate is not a function`'.

What's happening here, and how can I get around it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your closing bracket sequence is wrong

Change

```
paper.animate({x: 100, 500, "<")};
```

to

```
paper.animate({x: 100}, 500, "<");
```

**UPDATE**

From the docs, it does not seem that `animate` can be called directly on `paper`, but only on a sub-shape cut out of the canvas - that is why `firstshape.animate` works

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I typed it out fresh in the question, that error is not present in my actual code though. I have updated the question to reflect.

Answer (score 9):

You can’t animate paper object. Paper has no attributes to animate. But you could unite all your elements into [set](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#set) and then animate it.

Comment: Can I just take the opportunity to say: "thanks for Raphaël" =)

Answer (score 0):

You can not animate the drawing board... only the shapes inside it ..

paper is your drawing board.. whereas firstShape is a shape created inside the board ..

Comment: I was under the assumption that the primary 'drawing board' was simply the SVG element. Can you not animate / transform an entire SVG object?

Comment: @Jack, my understanding is that the `Raphael(..)` returns a canvas object. The rest are objects that reference this canvas and can be animated inside it .. i could be wrong though ..